# 1215 error when adding two foreign keys

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Can't solve this (hopefully) last error

I get a 1215 error at the creation of tournament_table but cannot explain it,is it because i try to add 2 foreign keys and I'm doing it wrong? How would I do it then? I cannot find a statisfying awnser on the internet.

If I can't fix it, the stack in my brain is gonna overflow

```
create table Poker_event
   (date_time       datetime    not null,
    min_players     int         not null,
    max_players     int         not null,
    house_number    int         not null, 
    postal_code     varchar(6)  not null,
primary key(date_time),
foreign key(house_number, postal_code)   references Location(house_number, postal_code) on delete cascade on update cascade);

create table Tournament
   (date_time   datetime    not null,
    prize       int         not null,
primary key(date_time),
foreign key(date_time)  references Poker_event(date_time) on delete no action on update cascade);

create table Tournament_round
   (round_nr    int       not null,
    date_time   datetime    not null,
primary key(date_time, round_nr),
foreign key(date_time)  references Tournament(date_time) on delete no action on update cascade);

create table Tournament_table
   (winner      int         not null,
    date_time   datetime    not null,
    round_nr    int         not null,
primary key(winner, date_time, round_nr),
foreign key(date_time)  references Tournament(date_time) on delete no action on update cascade,
foreign key(round_nr)   references Tournament_round(round_nr) on delete no action on update cascade)
```

Comment: Prediction: those composite keys are going to become painful. I'd use simple, integer surrogate keys, named `id`, as the primary key for each table. Foreign key columns would be named `table_id`, so then JOIN predicates are always of the form **`child.parent_id = parent.id`**. (Composite keys are valid and supported, and column names are just column names, so your design is workable. But my predication is that you are later going to wish you hadn't used composite primary keys.)

Comment: I would like to do that, but... the thing is, if I do that, I won't pass this class. I've got to keep my database in 3th normal form

Comment: In my opinion, the introduction of a simple surrogate primary key doesn't violate any of Codd's criteria for 3NF. And it doesn't vioate Boyce-Codd either (as long as the candidate keys don't overlap, and they wouldn't, because I'd also remove the redundant `datetime` attribute from the `Tournament_round` and `Tournament_table` table. (I'm not going to enter a debate; I'll leave it to the academia to debate whether the introduction of surrogate primary keys does violence to 3NF.) I prefer my primary keys to satisfy a list of desirable properties: simple, unique, immutable, anonymous, ...

Comment: Once the system is up and operational and in production... that's when the new requirement is revealed. Oh, that `date_time` we told you was unique in Tournament, turns out that isn't really unique. We can actually have two tournaments with the same exact `date_time`, just in different locations. Consider the impact of accommodating that requirement. The candidate key selected as PRIMARY KEY has just lost its uniqueness. DOH! And that impacts more than just the  `Tournament` table and the foreign key references. It also impacts *every* SQL statement that JOINs to the `Tournament` table.

Comment: well... once my teachers gonna pull up that trick on me, I'm gonna throw them in front of a bus or something. They aren't unique as far as I can see. I have to evaluate every week with my teacher, and did evaluate the accompanying RRM with em. And they said it was good. So I'll keep it that way, untill they say something else.

Comment: Well your database design is definitely workable, there are plenty of systems out there that use natural keys as primary keys. Regarding 3NF (or BCNF), wouldn't that foreign key reference from `tournament_table`(**`ttt`**) to the `tournament` table (**`t`**) be considered redundant (in terms of the logical model); **`ttt`** is related to `tournament_round` (**`tt`**), and **`tt`** is related to **`t`**; **`ttt`**'s relationship to **`t`** is already dependent on **`tt`**. (I know foreign key constraints are really an implementation detail of the physical model, not the logical model.)

Comment: from tournament_table to tournament_round? no, because I need to be able to see which players were at a table in which round. (there are multiple rounds in a pokermach with multiple tables) therfore I need to keep track of the rounds. which just adds compound keys.

Comment: I was asking about the other constraint in `Tournament_table`,  **`foreign key(date_time) references Tournament(date_time)`**, but I see now (in your answer) that you actually already removed that constraint, and now have just the one foreign key constraint referencing `Tournament_round`. (I kept that second one in the table definition in my answer, but I commented it out now.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was

```
create table Tournament_table
   (winner      int         not null,
    date_time   datetime    not null,
    round_nr    int         not null,
primary key(winner, date_time, round_nr),
foreign key(date_time)  references Tournament(date_time) on delete no action on update cascade,
foreign key(round_nr)   references Tournament_round(round_nr) on delete no action on update cascade)
```

it should have been

```
create table Tournament_table
   (winner      int         not null,
    date_time   datetime    not null,
    round_nr    int         not null,
primary key(winner, date_time, round_nr),
foreign key(date_time, round_nr)   references Tournament_round(date_time, round_nr) on delete no action on update cascade);
```

appereantly, this is a compound key.

Answer (score 0):

`round_nr` is not a column in `Tournament`

The last line of your `Tournament_table` definition:

```
 foreign key(round_nr) references Tournament(round_nr) 
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That referenced column, it doesn't exist. It looks like you intend `Tournament_table` to be a child of the `Tournament_round`. And you've got a composite primary key (ugghhh) on `Tournament_round`, a foreign key constraint would need to include both of those columns:

```
foreign key(date_time, round_nr) references Tournament_round(date_time,round_nr)
```

Also, in the first table definition (of `Tournament`) there's a foreign key reference to table `Poker_event`. We don't see the referenced table, so we don't know if that's a problem or not. Aside from those two issues, it looks like this should work.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

```
CREATE TABLE Tournament
( date_time   DATETIME    NOT NULL
, prize       INT         NOT NULL
, PRIMARY KEY(date_time)
-- , FOREIGN KEY(date_time) REFERENCES Poker_event(date_time) 
--     ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE Tournament_round
( round_nr    INT       NOT NULL
, date_time   DATETIME    NOT NULL
, PRIMARY KEY(date_time, round_nr)
, FOREIGN KEY(date_time) REFERENCES Tournament(date_time) 
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE Tournament_table
( winner      INT         NOT NULL
, date_time   DATETIME    NOT NULL
, round_nr    INT         NOT NULL
, PRIMARY KEY(winner, date_time, round_nr)
-- , FOREIGN KEY(date_time) REFERENCES Tournament(date_time)
--     ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
, FOREIGN KEY(date_time,round_nr) REFERENCES Tournament_round(date_time,round_nr) 
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

(The default storage engine is InnoDB)

```
3 queries executed, 3 success, 0 errors, 0 warnings
Query: create table Tournament ( date_time datetime ...
0 row(s) affected
--------------------------------------------------
Query: create table Tournament_round ( round_nr int ...
0 row(s) affected
--------------------------------------------------
Query: create table Tournament_table ( winner int ...
0 row(s) affected
```

---

Based on my experience working with relational databases (DB2, Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, MariaDB), my preference is for implementing a simple surrogate primary key for each "entity" table. (I distinguish between "entity" tables and other tables, such as "lookup" (list of values) tables, and "relationship" tables, tables that are added purely to resolve many-to-many relationships. (A pure relationship table won't have non-key attributes and won't itself be an entity in another relationship).

Obviously, I haven't done the data analysis and entity-relationship modeling for the particular problem domain you are working on. But based on the table definitions you show, here's an example of the equivalent table definitions, using surrogate keys. (In my opinion, the `id` columns do not  violate 3NF or BCNF since they would be considered "candidate keys", not non-key attributes. Notice that the non-anonymous key attributes, such as `date_time` have been removed from the child tables, since these attributes *would* now violate 3NF (since they aren't dependent on the key.)

```
CREATE TABLE poker_event
( id             INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY COMMENT 'pk' 
, location_id    INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'fk ref location.id'
, date_time      DATETIME     NOT NULL COMMENT 'event start time'
, min_players    INT          NOT NULL COMMENT 'minimum number of players'
, max_players    INT          NOT NULL COMMENT 'maximum number of players'
, UNIQUE KEY poker_event_UX1(date_time)
, CONSTRAINT FK_poker_event_location
    FOREIGN KEY (location_id) REFERENCES location(id)
);

CREATE TABLE tournament
( id             INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY COMMENT 'pk'
, poker_event_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'fk ref poker_event.id'
, prize          INT          NOT NULL COMMENT 'prize'
, CONSTRAINT FK_tournament_poker_event
    FOREIGN KEY (poker_event_id) REFERENCES poker_event(id)
);

CREATE TABLE tournament_round
( id             INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY COMMENT 'pk'
, tournament_id  INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'fk ref tournament.id'
, round_nr       INT          NOT NULL COMMENT 'round number'
, UNIQUE KEY tournament_round_UX1(tournament_id,round_nr)
, CONSTRAINT FK_tournament_round_tournament
    FOREIGN KEY (tournament_id) REFERENCES tournament(id)
);

CREATE TABLE tournament_table
( id                  INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY COMMENT 'pk'
, tournament_round_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'fk ref tournament_round.id'
, winner              INT NOT NULL COMMENT 'winner'
, UNIQUE KEY tournament_table_UX1(tournament_round_id,winner)
, CONSTRAINT FK_tournament_table_tournament_round
    FOREIGN KEY (tournament_round_id) REFERENCES tournament_round(id)
);
```

Comment: I'll edit in that table. I just left it out for the sake of the post becoming too long

Comment: edited that, but somehow I still can't get it working

Comment: I got it working my way, but thank you for your help